# Syncing state between React app and Firebase database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to React and I'm following an online tutorial. I've developed the code below as part of a Todo App. It is the logic for removing an existing todo item (object) from the state. The state is in the following format:

```
todos: {todo1: 'Throw the keyboard out of the window',
        todo2: 'Go and buy a new keyboard'}
```

...and here is the key code from my app:

```
var TodoApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      todos: {}
    };
  },
  removeTodo: function(key) {
    var todosCopy = Object.assign({}, this.state.todos);
    delete todosCopy[key];

    this.setState({
      todos: {...todosCopy}
    });
  }  
}
```

The above gets the job done and the selected todo is indeed removed when the `removeTodo` method is invoked.

The problem appears when the instructor links the app with the Firebase database via the [npm re-base library](https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base) so that if the user has already used the app, the `todos` state will be pre-populated.

He does it by adding the following method to the `TodoApp`:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  var base = Rebase.createClass('https://example-com.firebaseio.com/');
  base.syncState('todos', {
    context: this,
    state: 'todos',
  });
```

As soon as the above is added, my `removeTodo` method stops updating the state. But the instructor actually gets his app to work with his own version of the `removeTodo` method below:

```
removeTodo : function(key) {
  this.state.todos[key] = null;
  this.setState({
    todos : this.state.todos
  });
},
```

I don't think that he is following the best practice since we should not be mutating the state according to the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html). I would prefer to avoid this. So my questions are:

1. Why is his version of the `removeTodo` working and mine is not?
2. What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to avoid mutating the state and successfully sync state between the React app and the Firebase database by refactoring my `removeTodo` method in the following way:

```
removeTodo: function(key) {  
  this.setState({
    todos: {[key]: null}
  });
}
```